# Auto Azure SQL DB Creation -DACPAC task how to configure database Azure pricing model

Tags: azure-devops, azure-sql-database, config

I have just found out that MS are changing the default Azure PaaS DB config setting on create to use Vcore instead of DTU. I am using Azure Devops to build DBs from a GithHub repository via DACPACs using the Azure SQL Task. I would like to keep the DTU model for my builds.

The options I can see for implementing this are :

- Configure during the DACPAC Deploy task... I have not been able to find how to do this anywhere.
- Pre-create the DB and then run the DACPAC file into it.
- Set an azure default for any new DBs created. I have not been able to find a way of doing this.

For the second option I have successfully used the code snippet below for DB creation though cant find how I would create one with "standard S0 10 DTUs for example.

Any advice gratefully received..

New-AzureRmSqlDatabase -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup -ServerName $Servername -DatabaseName $DataBaseName

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many false starts due to deficiencies in the documentation due to the constant Azure churn I have a working script. This Script works and the web hooks allow it to be called from Azure Devops CI.

```
param
(
[Parameter (Mandatory = $false)]
[object] $WebhookData
)

Write-Output $WebhookData
# If runbook was called from Webhook, WebhookData will not be null.
if ($WebhookData) {

# Retrieve Params from Webhook request body
$params = (ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $WebhookData.RequestBody)

foreach ($param in $params)
{
    $DatabaseName = $param.DatabaseName
    $Edition = $param.Edition
    $PricingTier=$param.PricingTier
    Write-Output "Found $DatabaseName"
    Write-Output "Found $Edition"
    Write-Output "Found $PricingTier"

}


$connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"

try
{
    # Get the connection "AzureRunAsConnection "
    $servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         

    "Logging in to Azure..."
    Add-AzureRmAccount `
-ServicePrincipal `
-TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
-ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
-CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint 
}
catch {
    if (!$servicePrincipalConnection)
    {
        $ErrorMessage = "Connection $connectionName not found."
        throw $ErrorMessage
    } else{
        Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
        throw $_.Exception
    }
}

$ServerName = "ServerName"
$ResourceGroup = "ResourceGroupName"
#$PricingTierLocal ="S2"
#$EditionLocal ="Standard"

Set-AzureRmSqlDatabase  -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup -ServerName $ServerName -DatabaseName $DatabaseName  -Edition  $Edition  -RequestedServiceObjectiveName   $PricingTier

}
else {
# Error
write-Error "This runbook is meant to be started from an Azure webhook only."
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, you want to provision your Azure resources via some variety of idempotent configuration language. ARM templates are native, Terraform is a popular alternative. Run your ARM template deployment at the start of every deployment, then all of the necessary infrastructure for your application to run will be in place and properly configured.

If you want to do it with PowerShell, though, the [parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.sql/new-azurermsqldatabase?view=azurermps-6.13.0) you're looking for are `Edition` and `RequestedServiceObjectiveName`. I.E. `-Edition Standard -RequestedServiceObjectiveName S0`.

Comment: Thanks Daniel , Do you know how I would specify the DTU amount ? Is there a way you can interrogate the existing configuration to give you all the parameters you need for the create ?

Comment: `Get-AzureRmSqlServerServiceObjective` (or if you're using the Az module, `Get-AzSqlServerServiceObjective`) gives you a list of service objectives and the DTUs they provide. You don't specify DTUs, you specify a service objective that corresponds to some amount of DTUs.